# Determine week number based on starting date

Tags: php

I need help to create a function to determine the week number based on these 2 parameters:

1. Starting date
2. Specified date

For example, if I specify April 7, 2010 as the starting date & passed April 20, 2010 as the date to lookup, I would like the function to return WEEK 2. Another example, if I set March 6, 2010 as starting date and looked up April 5, 2010 then it should return WEEK 6.

I appreciate your time and help.

=================

## UPDATE

For instance:

Starting date: 3/6 - week1
Lookup date: 4/5

Week 2 starts from Mar 7-13.
Week 3 (3/14-3/20).
Week 4 (3/21-3/27). Week 5 (3/28-4/3).
So 4/5 falls under Week 6.

An idea is to use the Sunday of the starting date as the NEW* starting date. So instead of looking up 3/6, the function will use 2/28 as the starting date.

Comment: how come u got 6 week between March 6 and April 5

Comment: There are 30 days between march 6 and april 5, which should result in week 5. Can you explain how to you week 6 ?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. Yes the function needs to return Week 6, because I'm not trying to lookup the number of days/weeks based on the 2 dates. 

March 6 (Saturday, based on Sun - Sat calendar) is the starting date which falls under Week 1. Week 2 starts from Mar 7-13. Week 3 (3/14-3/20). Week 4 (3/21-3/27). Week 5 (3/28-4/3). So 4/5 falls under Week 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the number of days between the two dates, divide that number by `7` and take the `ceil` of the result:

```
$start_date = strtotime("2010-04-07");
$specified_date = strtotime("2010-04-20");
$num_of_days = ($specified_date - $start_date)/(60*60*24);
$week_num = ceil($num_of_days/7);
echo $week_num; // prints 2.
```

Comment: Why not divide by `(60*60*24*7)` in just one step?

Answer (score 1):

What about?

1. Determine the number of days since the epoch of the start date
2. ditto, the specified date
3. subtract
4. divide by 7

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know how you are going to receive your dates, I would do something like:

```
$starting = mktime(parsedStartingDate);
$lookup = mktime(parsedLookupDate);

$result = $lookup - $starting;
$result = (((($result / 60) / 60) / 24) / 7);

return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not being very clear this may or may not be what you're looking for:

```
// Example 1 (returns 2)
date('W', strtotime('April 20, 2010')) - date('W', strtotime('April 7, 2010'));

// Example 2 (returns 5)
date('W', strtotime('April 5, 2010')) - date('W', strtotime('March 6, 2010'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
$start_date = strtotime("2010-03-06"); // returns 1267862400

$start_date_week = strtotime("last sunday",$start_date); // 02-28

$specified_date = strtotime("2010-04-10"); // returns 1270882800

$specified_date_week = strtotime("next sunday",$specified_date); // 4-11 looking up the Next Sunday was also the key!

$num_of_days = ($specified_date_week - $start_date_week)/(60*60*24); // 41.958
$week_num = ceil($num_of_days/7); //6

echo $week_num;
```